# How can I enforce a grid width despite gaps pushing it beyond that width?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I just burnt myself trying to mimic a bootstrap-like 12-column layout using css grids. The issue I'm having is that grid content seem to have an inherent minimum width based on the column gap.

Please consider this code:

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  gap: 40px;
}

.col {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.col-3 {
  grid-column: 3 span / 3 span;
}

.col-4 {
  grid-column: 4 span / 4 span;
}

.col-5 {
  grid-column: 5 span / 5 span;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col col-3">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4">
      Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col col-5">
      Column 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The container width is 300px yet the grid items span over 440px. I suppose this behavior could make sense since the grid gap is 40px and there are 11 gaps *(40px*11=440px)*.

So in this situations there are two conflicting constraints – the grid should be 300px yet the gap between each column should be 40px. Now the latter constraint takes precedence over the first one. Is there any way to have the first constraint take precedence over the second one instead?

Here's an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lxq8ymc/12/).

Comment: What are you expecting? You set a gap of 40px 11 times....for a width of 300px container.

Comment: Sounds to me as though you actually want flexbox and space between

Comment: I think I am catching your drift, but not 100% sure, could you elaborate a little more so I can give you the best answer.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RwZZQog

Comment: @Paulie_D While I don't think the result it is unexpected, I'm expecting some way to control which constraint should have precedence over the other.

Comment: Well you can't. No-one would logically apply a 40px gap 11 times in a 300px container. The spec isn't designed for illogical things like that.

Comment: @Paulie_D Consider you have a 12-column grid design system and you want 40px column gap. This is a quite logical requirement. Now using grid and grid-gap this overflow on viewports < 440px, even if you span each item over the whole grid for those viewports.

Comment: The grid is logical the width constraint is not. You would not have a 40px at those widths.

Comment: I was hoping to have the gap configurable by a CMS, but since the gap could then be configured by a non-technical person this could easily just break the layout, e.g. on smaller viewports. I was hoping that it could break the *other* way in this situation, so that the gap is resized to fit its container, rather than the whole grid expanding outside of it.

Comment: Note – I'm not saying it's illogical that it expands outside its container, I'm just hoping I could opt out of this behavior by `max-width: 100%;` or something like this.